# How to develop disable private browsing option as inbuilt feature in firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am designing to develop a firefox extension which will offer inbuilt feature to stop private browsing. I have tried given below code, but still private browsing remains same.Please can anyone help me to figure this out? Given below my manifest.json code

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Cat Gifs!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "incognito":"not_allowed",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "stop private browsing".

Comment: @chrylis I want to built firefox extension to  not let my user to do private browsing.I want to disable private browsing option

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you want it to do that?

Comment: @chrylis for my university project i want to built extension which will prevent kids accessing pronographic content. The first step of that development will be disable private browsing to kids, such that they will not be able to browse without being tracking

Comment: I'm not certain you're familiar with what exactly "tracking" means in this context, and I don't think disabling private browsing (even if possible, which would probably require a custom browser distribution) would give you the functionality you want.

Comment: @chrylis when a user use private browsing he can browse whatever he want without keeping any records in browsing history. I want to prevent private browsing because of that. Yes I am novice to build browser extensions